# Loading pages into a div with JQuery, existing Javascript not working

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page I'm working on where a user clicks a link and it loads a new php file into an existing div. It works but the page that loads into the div will not function with existing Javascript stuff in the page.

I can include the 
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/admin.js"></script>`
into the loaded pages but when you flick back and forth between the pages I notice that RAM usage starts to go up and up, so I don't think this is the best way of doing it.

Any ideas how the loaded page can function with the already-loaded  javascript from the index page?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be inside a div? Can you use an `iframe`?

Comment: Ideally so I don't have to mess about with doing all the includes etc. to make the page have basic functionality.

Comment: you mean event handlers don't apply to the html you have appended dynamically ?

Comment: What is the "already-loaded javascript" in your index page doing? Can you provide some code of it? It will depend highly on that.

Comment: Memory leak? Or are you just not watching long enough for garbage collection?

Comment: Nah was just not waiting long enough for garbage collection. But if a user would be clicking around from area to area quickly then each click would take up another 3mb of RAM, after not many clicks you're taking up far too much memory than it should. The user probably wouldn't notice but it's not about that is it. It just shouldn't happen anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `bind` or `click` type events change to using something like [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) if you are required to use jquery version less than 1.9)

OR/AND

In your function that loads in the page via ajax provide a call back that initiates only what is needed. Example:

```
$('#myDiv').load('ajax/page.php', function(){

    $('#myDiv a').customPlugin('whatever');
    $('#myDiv button').bind('click', function(){
        window.open('http://www.google.com/', 'some-window');
    });

});
```

Comment: live is depercated since jquery 1.7 & removed since 1.9

Comment: `live` is old-school these days

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. "

Comment: I've updated the answer. Which is what you should have just done.

Comment: live broke it but the loading the code in on the function worked great :) Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

bind your events like this :

```
 $(document).on({
           "event"  : function(e) {},
             ...

          }, "selector");
```